# Does background-image reset other background properties previously declared?

Tags: css, background

Several DIVS are to have the same background properties, except for the image itself. When trying to set them in a multiple selector, The properties don't seem to be retained when the `background-image` property on the individual selector is set. Can someone clarify if / which background properties are retained / reset?

```
.home-content-1, .home-content-1.5, .home-content-2, .home-content-3{
  padding: 3em 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url(test.png); /* added this to see if maybe it's necessary */
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.home-content-1{
  padding: 3em 0;
  background-image: url('../images/content-1-bg.png');
}
```

Comment: `.home-content-1` will have the new background, the others are unchanged

Comment: `.home-content-1.5` is not valid because `1.5` it is breaking CSS with `.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st `.home-content-1.5` is not valid class name and `1.5` is breaking CSS with `.` (which is a class selector)

> REF: A class name must begin with an underscore (_), a hyphen (-), or a letter(a–z), followed by any number of hyphens, underscores, letters, or numbers.

2nd after fixed that `1.5` class name with for example `1_5`. later css rule will overwrite the previous one with the same attribute defined, ex:

```css
.home-content-1, .home-content-1_5, .home-content-2, .home-content-3{
  padding: 3em 0 0 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/); /* added this to see if maybe it's necessary */
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.home-content-1 {
  padding: 3em 0;
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/200x200);
}
```

```html
<div class="home-content-1"></div>
<div class="home-content-1_5"></div>
<div class="home-content-2"></div>
<div class="home-content-3"></div>
```

Comment: ah, foolish mistake. of course the dot breaks the naming convention. Must have been a late night.